# Grouping timestamps with descriptions

Tags: javascript, regex, timestamp

I have data for tasks that were recorded with a time sheet app. I'm trying to parse the breaks for each task.

An example break string attached to a task can look like this:

> 1:19pm – 10:33pm ate tacos 10:35pm – 11:38pm 12:40am – 1:24am took a
> nap

I need to group this into time stamps with their associated descriptions. The above should be grouped like:

> 1:19pm – 10:33pm ate tacos
>
> 10:35pm – 11:38pm
>
> 12:40am – 1:24am took a nap

The description for a break interval can have basically any characters or be any length. Some intervals don't have descriptions.

I figure regex would be the simplest way to get an array of intervals with their descriptions (if they have one).

So far I have:

```
\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m\s–\s\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m
```

which matches the time stamps `1:19pm – 10:33pm` , `10:35pm – 11:38pm` , and `12:40am – 1:24am`

I am using JavaScript, and the [match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) function, to parse this data. I want to make a regular expression that will match the time stamp and everything that follows it until the next time stamp.

I'm a beginner with regex so go easy on me. I've been at this for hours, watched several videos, read tutorial blogs, and been experimenting with [regex101](https://regex101.com). Anchors, lookahead/behinds, are confusing and I can't seem to get anything to do what I want. Not looking to become an expert in writing regular expressions, but I would really like learning something new that can be directly applied to what I'm doing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
(\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m\s*–\s*\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m)(\D*(?:\d(?!\d?:\d{2}[ap]m\s)\D*)*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hX1wB8/1)

The problem you face is ***matching a text that does not match a specific pattern***. This can be achieved either with a **tempered greedy token** or an **unroll-the-loop** technique. The latter is preferable since it involves less backtracking. My regex is based on that technique.

Here is the regex explanation:

- `(\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m\s*–\s*\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m)` - matches and *captures into Group #1* time period (I just added outer parentheses and the `*` quantifiers to `\s` classes) - as it is your regex, I won't go into detail
- `(\D*(?:\d(?!\d?:\d{2}[ap]m\s)\D*)*)` - this is an unrolled `.*?(?=\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m\s)` construct matching anything up to the first `\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m\s` pattern. It is placed in Group #2.

  - `\D*` - 0 or more characters other than a digit
  - `(?:\d(?!\d?:\d{2}[ap]m\s)\D*)*` - 0 or more sequences of...

    - `\d(?!\d?:\d{2}[ap]m\s)` - a digit (`\d`) that is not followed by 1 or 0 digits followed with `:` followed with 2 digits, then `a` or `p`, then `m`, and then a whitespace
    - `\D*` - again, 0 or more characters other than a digit.

JS demo:

```js
var re = /(\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m\s*–\s*\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m)(\D*(?:\d(?!\d?:\d{2}[ap]m\s)\D*)*)/ig; 
var str = '1:19pm – 10:33pm ate tacos 10:35pm – 11:38pm 12:40am – 1:24am took a nap';
var m;
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    document.getElementById("r").innerHTML += "Period: " + m[1] + "<br/>";
    document.getElementById("r").innerHTML   += "Description: " + m[2] + "<br/><br/>";
}
```

```html
<div id="r"/>
```

Comment: I thought you were interested in organizing the output in some more readable form, so I suggested two capture groups. Note that the other working solution is using a construct that can lead to a catastrophic backtracking if your input is large. Unroll-the-loop regexes are not that prone to that problem.

Comment: Note that in case the regex pattern is known beforehand, the [*unroll-the-loop technique* (or *Unrolled Star Alternation Solution*)](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#unrolled_staralt) is the most appropriate to match up to the closest occurrence of a subpattern. In case you are using a variable, you have to use a [*tempered greedy token*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) or a non-regex solution if it is not efficient enough.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure this can be simplified, but the following regular expression seems to work:

[**Example Here**](https://regex101.com/r/uM5vM2/1)

```
/(\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m\s–\s\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m(?:.(?!\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m))*)/g
```

```js
var input = '1:19pm – 10:33pm ate tacos 10:35pm – 11:38pm 12:40am – 1:24am took a nap';
var matches = input.match(/(\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m\s–\s\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m(?:.(?!\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m))*)/g);

for (var i = 0; i < matches.length; i++) {
  snippet.log(matches[i]);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Output:

> 1:19pm – 10:33pm ate tacos
>
> 10:35pm – 11:38pm
>
> 12:40am – 1:24am took a nap

Comment: You are using a construct similar to a tempered greedy token. My regex based on the unroll the loop technique is  much more efficient because it does not test each character, and works with multiline content without any additional tweaks. Your `(?:.(?!\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m))*` will choke on a newline.

Comment: @stribizhev I got it; yours is clearly better. I'm not a regex expert like you :)

Comment: Still, most people think that a regex must be readable, not effecient, so I often "lose" the accepted marks :)

Comment: Your solution is quite good for a scenario when the pattern to negate is unknown (e.g. user-defined) and the regex is instantiated with variables. Unrolled solution will be difficult to apply then.

Answer (score 2):

hope it will help:

https://regex101.com/r/dV7vY5/1

> (\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m) – (\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m)([\s|a-z|A-Z]+)

output:

> 1:19pm – 10:33pm ate tacos
>
> 10:35pm – 11:38pm
>
> 12:40am – 1:24am took a nap

and you can acess each patter:

```
 $1 - first hour  (1:19pm)
 $2 - second hour (10:33pm)
 $3 - string      ( ate tacos)
```

example below:

```js
var string = '1:19pm – 10:33pm ate tacos 10:35pm – 11:38pm 12:40am – 1:24am took a nap';
var regex = /(\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m) – (\d{1,2}:\d{2}[ap]m)([\s|a-z|A-Z]+)/gi;
var eachMatche = string.match(regex);

for (var i = 0; i < eachMatche.length; i++) {
  snippet.log(eachMatche[i]);
  snippet.log('period : '+ eachMatche[i].replace(regex,'$1') +' - ' + eachMatche[i].replace(regex,'$2'));
  snippet.log('description : '+eachMatche[i].replace(regex,'$3'));
}
```

```html
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: What if the description contains Unicode characters? You only can match ASCII letters, literal `|`, and whitespace now with `[\s|a-z|A-Z]`.

Comment: good point! I guess it's just enhance for this situation! if you have the answer update my code. :) thanks @stribizhev

Comment: I provided my own answer.

Comment: @stribizhev that's not a race you can contribute to other answer as well.

Comment: I agree it is not a contest. What I wanted to point out is that OP does not state what is present in the description, what characters it can include. Since there is no clear restriction, we can only use an exclusion approach or a lazy dot matching with `[^]` or `[\s\S]` construct and a lookahead. Your whitelist approach can turn out insufficient here.

Comment: @stribizhev I did state that the description can contain any character or be any length.